# How do comments in ERB affect performance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

When writing Rails views, I've been thinking of using the ERB comment syntax instead of regular HTML comments for comment my code. The benefit is that the code is still nicely commented, but doesn't get rendered out to the public-facing HTML page.

Is there an impact on rendering performance if I were to do:

`<%# This is my comment in ERB %>` vs. `<!-- This is my comment in HTML -->` ?

Comment: This would be very easy to test/measure yourself, but the important thing is, it *doesn't matter*. Ruby's strength isn't performance. Write the most elegant maintainable code you can and worry about performance if it actually becomes a problem. Chances are you'll wind up caching the rendered template anyways.

Comment: Beyond what @meagar said, I think it's better not to leave comment there. Allow me to be a bit opinionated, comments in erb would look ugly. And as erb is the final consumer of various API there is little point to comment.

Answer (score 0):

You would gain a little performance increase using `<%# This is my comment in ERB %>`. Also, using the html comment your code will be rendered as a HTML comment, available to the users of the website, which would not be a good idea.